# I accidentally deleted an admin user and all their content is now gone from the site.

Tags: wp-admin, users

Is there any way to get the site content back?

Comment: You can try checking the `wp_posts` table for the revisions of the content they had created. I am not sure if WordPress deletes them if you delete a user and hence all his content.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear about the bad luck.  You're going to have to use the backup you created.  Or check with your hosting provider for the backup they've been keeping for you.